# Handle Laravel app.php Service Providers for prod/dev use

Tags: php, laravel

Installing package using `composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer --dev`. Package is correctly sent to the require-dev in composer.json which also requires a Service Provider. However, when running `composer install --no-dev` I'm getting error:

`Class 'Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider' not found`

This makes sense since it cannot find this Service Provider since it's only installing the required production packages.

What would be a good practice to tackle handling the app.php Autoloaded Service Providers for various environments or in this case just Local(dev) & Production?

Comment: Try to delete the files under bootstrap/cache before running `composer install --no-dev`

Comment: @stefket I get the same `Class 'Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider' not found` error in doing so

Comment: Sorry, didn't read about the entry in the app.php file. This package adds the service provider via autoloading to your app, so you don't have to add this entry to your app.php. And when you run the composer install command with the --no-dev option, the service provider will not be loaded.